# How to Configure a Hotplugged Network Interface with a Static IP Address

Tags: ubuntu, networking, dhcp, ubuntu-11.10

I have a device that I connect to my host Ubuntu machine via [Ethernet over USB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_over_USB). It shows up as usb0 in ifconfig and the device always has the same address: 192.168.0.1. I have the following two problems:

1. When I initially connect the device, the interface will connect and disconnect several times before settling down. I suspect this is because the dhclient is trying to obtain an IP address. The device does not support DHCP and this fails several times.
2. After the interface is stable, I have to configure the interface manually with ifconfig.

To solve the two issues I tried configuring **/etc/networking/interfaces:**

```
...
    allow-hotplug usb0
    iface usb0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.2
...
```

This does not seem to work at all and the interface never shows up. I also tried configuring the interface in **/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf**:

```
...
interface "usb0" {
  fixed-address 192.168.0.2;
}
...
```

Anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the device not supporting DHCP?  This is not something a device can choose to support or not support.

Comment: @Paul: What I meant is that the device will never act as a DHCP server and give an IP address to the host.

Comment: What is this device?  It is a computer of some kind, a phone or something?  Can you provide an excerpt of `dmesg` when it is plugged in?